# Difficulty expressing $f(\alpha)$, with $\alpha$ being a root of $f(x)$ as a polynomial of degree at most 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I am trying to solve this following problem:

Let $\alpha$ be a root of $\alpha^3 + \alpha^2 + 1 = \mathbb{F}_5[x]$. Express $2\alpha(\alpha + 1)^{-1}$ as a polynomial of $\alpha$ with degree at most $2$ and coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_5$.

So far, I have the following: My strategy was to express $2\alpha(\alpha + 1)^{-1}$ as some multiple of the multiplicative inverse $\alpha^{-1}$, since in my calculation, I determined that I could express the multiplicative inverse as a polynomial of degree $2$: $4(\alpha^2 + \alpha)$. However, in my final step I have $\cfrac{1}{2(\alpha - 1)}$ and I'm not sure how to transform this into just a multiple of $\cfrac{1}{\alpha}$

$$
\alpha^3 + \alpha^2 + 1 = 0\\
1 = -(\alpha^3 + \alpha^2) = 4(\alpha^3 + \alpha^2)\\
\alpha = 4(\alpha^4 + \alpha^3)\\
\cfrac{1}{\alpha} = 4(\alpha^2 + \alpha)\\
\cfrac{2\alpha}{(\alpha + 1)} = \cfrac{2}{4(\alpha^4 + 2\alpha^3 + \alpha^2)}
$$

Comment: Hint: if $\alpha^3+\alpha^2+1=0$ we can subtract and factor to get: $1=-\alpha^2(\alpha+1)$. Next multiply by $(\alpha+1)^{-1}$ to get $(\alpha+1)^{-1}=-\alpha^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing $a$ instead of $\alpha$ for brevity,

Since $a$ is non zero, $a^{-1}$ makes sense.

$2a(a+1)^{-1}=2a^2a^{-1} (a+1)^{-1}=2a^2 (a^2+a)^{-1}=2a^2 (-a^{-1})^{-1}=-2a^2a=3a^3=-3(a^2+1)=2a^2+2$